# Display leading zeroes in numericupdown control (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, controls

I have a numericupdown control on a C# Windows Form, and am interested in adding a leading zero to its value if it is < 10. (It is for the user to enter the minutes value of a time.)

I am not very familiar with overrides/inheriting yet in C# but it is looking as though I may have to do that.

It looks like [this post](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=33748685&threadid=31842634) on EggheadCafe has the answer I need. Is it as simple as making a new class and then creating a control of that new class?

```
public class TestNum : NumericUpDown
{
protected override void ValidateEditText()
{
if (base.UserEdit)
{
base.ValidateEditText();
}
}

protected override void UpdateEditText()
{
Text = Convert.ToInt32(base.Value).ToString("00");
}
}
```

When I try this, I am not sure how to create the new control that takes advantage of this class. I am using Visual Studio 2008. Still very new to windows forms. Thanks for any advice.

**EDIT**

I was able to make this work by editing the Designer-created code so that instead of the new control being of the original class, it was of the new one. So after adding the class above, I did the following (these changes are in two different locations, but I am only showing the lines that mattered):

Changed:

```
this.numTest = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
private System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown numTest;
```

To:

```
this.numTest = new SampleForm.TestNum();
private TestNum numTest;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this newly created class in your form. It doesn't replace all NumericUpDown controls, it's a subclass.

Add the project which contains this class to the toolbox (Tools->Toolbox Items... - if memory serves) and you should be able to drag the control onto the form where you want to use it.

Comment: The UI control class must be contained in a separately compiled assembly (for it to appear in the toolbox and be usable for VS), so it must be contained in its own project.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems Cecil Has a Name is right, there doesn't seem to be a way to add this control to the toolbox.

Comment: I was able to make this work by editing the Designer-created code, which I will edit into the question for clarity. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

Why not just use a `DateTimePicker` control?  Set its `ShowNumericUpDown` property to true and set its `Format` property to Custom and set the `CustomFormat` property to hh:mm:ss.

Perhaps this will be useful for you.

Comment: This is a great idea, I didn't realize I could do that. +1 for the help, though I wound up discovering a way to implement the change to the numericupdown.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this by looking for "NumericUpDown Display Hex with Leading Zero's"

```
public class HexNumericUpDown : System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown
{
    public HexNumericUpDown()
    {
        Hexadecimal = true;
    }

    protected override void ValidateEditText()
    {
        if (base.UserEdit)
        {
            base.ValidateEditText();
        }
    }

    protected override void UpdateEditText()
    {
        Text = System.Convert.ToInt64(base.Value).ToString("X" + HexLength);
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(4)]
    public int HexLength
    {
        get { return m_nHexLength; }
        set { m_nHexLength = value; }
    }

    public new System.Int64 Value
    {
        get { return System.Convert.ToInt64(base.Value); }
        set { base.Value = System.Convert.ToDecimal(value); }
    }

    private int m_nHexLength = 4;
 }
```

Answer (score -5):

Use date time picker with following properties:

1. Format = Custom
2. CustomFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
3. ShowUpDown = True